# Animation delay, how to hide the item first?

Tags: css

I have a slide in animation on a button element.  I want to delay this by 1s, how would I hide the element first so it doesn't appear onscreen and then disappear for the animation?
I currently sits on the page then disappears when the animation starts

Any help appreciated

Css

```
.btn {
   animation: fadeInAnimation ease 2.2s;
   animation-iteration-count: 1; 
   animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

key frames

```
@keyframes fadeInAnimation { 
        0% { 
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-250%); 
        } 
        100% { 
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(0);
         } 
    }
```

Comment: ```opacity: 0``` in the ```.btn``` ruleset?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself with

`animation-fill-mode: both`

Thanks to anyone who read this